# "Segmentation fault" with large files

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to convert a graph from ASCII DIMACS format to binary using this tool — http://code.google.com/p/dimacs-converter/source/browse/asc2bin.c.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work with large files (>2GB); the output is "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". How can I fix this problem?

Comment: How do you normally debug a .c program?  Have you tried using a debugger (e.g. GDB) obtain a stacktrace?

Comment: 2 GB. Sounds a lot like the limit of a signed integer. Might have something to do with using `int` (32 bit signed type) where you should use a `long int` (64 bit depending on compiler). When the number gets bigger than 2G it looks negative and points before the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 2):

This code has `#define MAX_NR_VERTICES 10000` in `genbin.h`.

Also it performs no error checking as to whether vertices read in from the file exceed this size or not, it will just write invalid memory if the file has a vertex numbered `10000` or more.

Perhaps your "large file" does contain more than 10,000 vertices?

This code has very poor error-checking in general, there are a number of things you could do in your input file that will just cause this code to write invalid memory without any warning.

If you want to modify this code to work with files of over 10,000 vertices, I would suggest dynamically allocating `Bitmap` once you have read and validated `Nr_vert`, and also add error-checking to every read operation. (and fix line 77 which has a wrong attempt at error checking).

Comment: Eeeeee…you don't often see K&R C code these days.  Of course, since it has a modification date of September 1993 for one change, it is not new code — back then, K&R was probably still a better choice, but that was no longer automatically the case by, say, the end of 1995, and by 2000, it was not a good idea.

Comment: Probably a case of "if it ain't broke don't fix it" from the maintainers

Comment: Well, yeah, changing 10000 to 50000 fixed the problem. Thanks a lot and my apologies to community for the stupid question!